# How to solve this cubic Diophantine equation?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

So I recently came across this problem:

$\large{x^{3}+ (x+1)^{3}+\cdots\cdots+(x+15)^{3}=y^{3}}$

Find how many ordered pairs for $\large{(x,y)}$ satisfy the above equation. Both $x,y$ are positive integers.

I can do it using computer program but this problem was supposed to be solved by hand and I have no idea how. How can I do it?

EDIT: The other question doesn't have any answer either.

Comment: Is $x$ a positive integer?

Comment: @ajotatxe both x and y are positive integers.

Comment: @ajotatxe if $(x,y)$ is a solution, so is $(-x-15, -y)$, so it wouldn't add much. But the assumption should be in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: @ProfessorVector added that.

Comment: I don't know if this helps:$$$$
The sum of the $n$ first cubes is
$$\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$

Then, the LHS becomes
$$\frac{(x+15)^2(x+16)^2-(x-1)^2x^2}4$$

Comment: @ajotatxe looks like a good simplification, let me try it out.

Comment: I get that $(2x+15)(x^2+15x+120)$ must be a cube. I haven't the foggiest on how to continue.

Comment: @ajotatxe Since $2x+15$ is odd, $$\gcd(2x+15,x^2+15x+120) = \gcd(2x+15,4x^2+60x+480) = \gcd(2x+15,30x+480) = \gcd(2x+15,255).$$ So one of the two must be $d$ times a cube, and the other $d^2$ times a cube for some $d\mid 255$. Not sure how much that helps, though.

Comment: As $x^2+15x+120$ is even, $y$ must be even, so $y^3$ is a multiple of $8$, so $x^2+15x+120$ is a multiple of $8$ and $x\equiv 0,1 \pmod 8$

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+(+(x%2B15)%5E2(x%2B16)%5E2-x%5E2(x-1)%5E2)%2F4%3Dy%5E3+in+integers) finds only $(-8,-8)$ and $(-7,8)$, so no solutions in positive integers.  These are easy to check because $15$ of the cubes add to $0$.